# Rx java Operators; Encapsulating data flow into custom Operators

Tags: java, reactive-programming, netflix, rx-java

Lets say I'm observing an observable in a very specific way.

```
    resultObservable = anotherObservable.filter(~Filter code~).take(15);
```

I'd like to create a custom operator that combines two predefined operators like filter, and take. Such that it behaves like

```
    resultObservable = anotherObservable.lift(new FilterAndTake(15));
```

or...

```
    resultObservable = anotherObservable.FilterAndTake(15);
```

So far Im comfortable with writing a very specific operator that can do this. And I can lift that operator.

But, given my currently limited knowledge of rx java, this would involve re-writing the take and filter functionality every time I need to use it in a custom operator.

Doing this is fine, But I'd rather re-use pre-existing operators that are maintained by an open source community, as well as recycle operators I've created.

Something also tells me I lack adequate knowledge about operators and subscribers.

Can someone recommend tutorials that aren't rx-java documentation?
I say this because, while docs explain general concepts, it isolates the concepts and general contexts of their functionality leaving no examples to inspire more robust applications of RX java.

**So essentailly**

I'm trying to encapsulate custom-dataflows into representative operators. Does this functionality exist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not aware of some special function (or sugar) that composes `Operator` objects. But you can simply create a new Operator to compose existing Operators.
Here's a working example of the `FilterAndTake` Operator:

```
public class FilterAndTake<T> implements Observable.Operator<T, T> {

    private OperatorFilter<T> filter;
    private OperatorTake<T> take;

    public FilterAndTake(Func1<? super T, Boolean> predicate, int n) {
        this.filter = new OperatorFilter<T>(predicate);
        this.take = new OperatorTake<T>(n);
    }

    @Override
    public Subscriber<? super T> call(final Subscriber<? super T> child) {
        return filter.call(take.call(child));
    }
}
```

And then you can use it as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Observable<Integer> xs = Observable.range(1, 8);

    Func1<Integer, Boolean> predicate = new Func1<Integer, Boolean>() {
        @Override
        public Boolean call(Integer x) {
            return x % 2 == 0;
        }
    };

    Action1<Integer> action = new Action1<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void call(Integer x) {
            System.out.println("> " + x);
        }
    };

    xs.lift(new FilterAndTake<Integer>(predicate, 2)).subscribe(action);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A bit late to the party, but that's why `compose` exists:

```
Observable
.from(....)
.flatMap(... -> ....)
.compose(filterAndTake(15))
.subscribe(...)

public <T> Transformer<T,T> flterAndTake(int num) {
  return source -> source
     .filter(~Filter code~)
     .take(num);
}
```